# Are kills you make after a checkpoint reset if you die in Tomb Raider 2013?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In game I quickly browsed through the menu pages (map, gears, skills, weapons). I could not find a statistics page there. Is there an other location to check for example how many kills you have made with a specific weapon? I would like to know if kills you have made after a checkpoint are reset when you die. I should be close to my 50 bow kills and 50 headshots by now ;)

Comment: Not that I know of. The only ones I have left are the shotgun and roping someone off a ledge... Either I'm not doing it right or it's just not updating at all any more since beating the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't "farm" checkpoints. i.e. you can't kill several enemies die/reload checkpoints and kill again. See descriptions for the *kill X enemies with Y weapon* trophies on [this guide](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/tomb-raider/190879-tomb-raider-trophy-guide-road-map.html#post3454442):

> Note that you can’t select reload checkpoint and keep killing enemies, as that won’t count as extra kills

Comment: Yes, they _will_ count as extra kills. I got the 25 counters, shotgun, machine gun and looting trophies in a single place by reloading the same checkpoint over and over again. Experience points are also kept.